# Blender IndexError: bpy_prop_collection

Tags: python, libgdx, blender, index-error

I try write a game with GoranM/bdx plugin. When i create plate with texture and  try export to code I get fatal error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Myuser\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\bdx\ops\exprun.py", line 225, in execute
>       export(self, context, bpy.context.scene.bdx.multi_blend_export, bpy.context.scene.bdx.diff_export)
>     File "C:\Users\Myuser\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\bdx\ops\exprun.py", line 123, in export
>       bpy.ops.export_scene.bdx(filepath=file_path, scene_name=scene.name, exprun=True)
>     File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 189, in **call**
>       ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
>   RuntimeError: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Myuser\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\bdx\exporter.py", line 903, in execute
>       return export(context, self.filepath, self.scene_name, self.exprun, self.apply_modifier)
>     File "C:\Users\Myuser\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\bdx\exporter.py", line 829, in export
>       "models": srl_models(objects, apply_modifier),
>     File "C:\Users\Myuser\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\bdx\exporter.py", line 117, in srl_models
>       verts = vertices(mesh)
>     File "C:\Users\Myuser\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\bdx\exporter.py", line 53, in vertices
>       vert_uv = list(uv_layer[li].uv)
>   IndexError: bpy_prop_collection[index]: index 0 out of range, size 0
>
> location: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py:189
>
> location: :-1

Maybe someone had same problem and you know how to fix it?

Comment: The error sounds like it expects the object to have uv's and it doesn't. You should [unwrap it](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/introduction.html), or at least [create a new uvlayout](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv/layout_management.html#uv-maps-panel) and then try.

Comment: same. if i add texture image then i get this error.

Answer (score -1):

Go into Object Mode before calling that function.

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT', toggle=False)